# Angular 2 webpack bundle size

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to reduce the size of my webpack bundles. The project is built around angular 2 & webpack.

Back in a day when I was using angular 2.0.0 ,the bundle size was about 2mb, which is fine.

But now, after updates to v4 and v5, bundle sizes are skyrocketed to >15mb.Even after Uglify/Babili-minify/Closure Compiler

Could anyone spot anything obvious or suggest ways to improve bundle size? (apart of mentioned glify/Babili-minify/Closure Compiler,because they are reducing the size only by 2-3mb...out of 20mb)

Webpack configs:
https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/webpack.common.js
https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/webpack.dev.js

Package.json
https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/package.json

tsconfig:
https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/tsconfig.json

thank you for your help

**Update:**
The webpack 2.3 used to generate large source maps and the main js files was about 3-4 mb. I wonder  if it because of webpack 3.8

Comment: One thing to check is that someone didn't accidentally `import Rx from "rxjs/Rx";` or something similar.

Comment: https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/Scripts/vendor.ts#L12

Comment: Also i would advice you not to import all '@angular/material';

Comment: Thank you man, changed it to https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp/blob/master/NgMultiApp/Scripts/vendor.ts , but the size of the vendor bundle didn't reduce much :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in --d option of webpack, which prevents sourcemaps generation.
After as I removed it, the source maps was generated and the bundle sizes was reduces from 20 mb to 3mb!

--d is a shortcut for:

```
--debug --devtool cheap-module-eval-source-map --output-pathinfo
```